# Algebra structure on dual to coalgebra

Tags: category-theory, hopf-algebras, quantum-groups, coalgebras

I'm trying to prove the following theorem using braided diagrams:

> Let $(C,\Delta,\varepsilon)$ be a finite-dimensional coalgebra. There is an algebra structure on $C^*$ given by multiplication $\Delta^*\circ \zeta$ and unit $\eta=\varepsilon^*$, where $C^*\otimes C^* \stackrel{\zeta}{\cong}\left(C\otimes C\right)^*$ is a natural isomorphism of vector spaces.

I have only problem with proving that the unit is well-defined.
In the proof which I found in one article is a statement, that there is the following equality :

[image]

Why it is true ? It isn't obvious for me.

Comment: Use the unit–counit equation to get rid of the S-shaped bend, and then push past the braiding.

Comment: I don't understand. What does it mean "push past the braiding" ? How to do it on diagram ?

Comment: Recall that the braiding is a natural transformation. @Martin: I think you forgot a "don't".

Comment: @ Najib Idrissi, naturality means that $(g\otimes f)\tau=\tau(f\otimes g)$. What are $f$ and $g$ in this case ? Probably one of them should be identity, but after use this fact we still have a flip-map $\tau$.

Comment: One is the identity, the other is the counit. Yes, there's still a braiding/flip map, but if you look closely at the RHS of your picture you'll see that there's a braiding there too... (BTW: if you want to ping someone, don't put a space between the at-sign (`@`) and the name, otherwise it won't work).

Comment: It works. Thanks ! :)